# Cycle partial result in graph

Tags: r, graph, error-handling, igraph

I have received the following message while displaying a graph (I am using igraph library):

```
Warning message:
In .Call("R_igraph_layout_reingold_tilford", graph, root, mode,  :
  At structural_properties.c:3297 :graph contains a cycle, partial result is returned
```

Does it mean that not all the graph has been displayed?

And in this case, how can I skip this error and draw anyway the graph?

Comment: Anyway I used the layout fruchterman.reingold  and it gives me no errors

Comment: Question very unclear in its current form. Read the help page on composing questions. Present full code.Don't add modifications with the comment mechanism. Learn to edit. And if the problem no longer exist, then either delete the question or add your own answer, again with full code.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, the layout algorithm used for you graph is used for tree-like graphs.

```
 layout_reingold_tilford: Reingold-Tilford tree layout, useful for (almost) tree-like graphs.
```

If your graph contains cycles, then runtime warning be showed in the screen.
You can change the algorithm to **'kk'** if the graph is a directed graph or you can choose other algorithm, according to your needs. Please, check the tutorial in the documentation for more information. This tutorial is python-based, but the idea is the same. [igraph Tutorial](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html)